# Placing the table caption inside the top row

Tags: tables, captions

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!h]
\caption{Caption (not here)} 
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|cc|}
\hline 
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Table 1---Caption(should be here)} \\ 
Property A & Property B \\ \hline 
a1 & b1 \\ 
a2 & b2 \\ \hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The code generates the table in figure. I know, it's perfect. But the journal I am writing my paper for requires the caption to be placed at **Should be here**. Also note that, instead of colon, there is an em-dash following the table number which joins the table number and the caption without any white space.

How can I do it?

Comment: Does that journal provide a template? If they give guidelines like this, most likely they give templates too.

Comment: @HarishKumar No, unfortunately not.

Comment: My sympathies :-)

Comment: In case of the default caption style, is there a way to override the colon (:), after table numbering, by an em-dash?

Comment: See my edit, in which the caption format is redefined.

Answer (score 5):

A brute force solution, but expectations of a journal (Which one? Maybe it offers an own class?) are very strange. The first and third tables are only for controlling the proper beghaviour.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!h]
\caption{Caption (not here)} 
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|cc|}
\hline 
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Table 1---Caption(should be here)} \\ 
Property A & Property B \\ \hline 
a1 & b1 \\ 
a2 & b2 \\ \hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

Changes only here

\begin{table}[!h]
\refstepcounter{table} %% increment the 'table' counter first
%\caption{Caption (not here)} 
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|cc|}
\hline 
%\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Table 1---Caption(should be here)} \\ 
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\tablename~\thetable---Caption(should be here)}\\
Property A & Property B \\ \hline 
a1 & b1 \\ 
a2 & b2 \\ \hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}



\begin{table}[!h]
\caption{Caption (not here)} 
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|cc|}
\hline 
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Table 1---Caption(should be here)} \\ 
Property A & Property B \\ \hline 
a1 & b1 \\ 
a2 & b2 \\ \hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I've applied one more little change: the `\refstepcounter` directive needs to be outside the `tabular` environment.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke It works fine, but the list of table is empty. Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Here, I just `\vspace` the `tabular` upward to overlay the caption, and then add some `\kern` to the blank line at the top of the table, allowing for the caption width.

EDITED to provide emdash in caption (by editing `article` definition of `\@makecaption`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\long\def\@makecaption#1#2{%
  \vskip\abovecaptionskip
  \sbox\@tempboxa{#1---#2}%
  \ifdim \wd\@tempboxa >\hsize
    #1---#2\par
  \else
    \global \@minipagefalse
    \hb@xt@\hsize{\hfil\box\@tempboxa\hfil}%
  \fi
  \vskip\belowcaptionskip}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!h]
\caption{Caption goes here~} 
\vspace{-12pt}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|cc|}
\hline 
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\kern1.6in} \\ 
Property A & Property B \\ \hline 
a1 & b1 \\ 
a2 & b2 \\ \hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you should observe the request for an em-dash in the caption.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Done.